# Will this one to two audio splitter work?

Tags: audio

I am completely new to electrical engineering, and I figured before I solder something that just won't work I decided to ask here for some confirmation. My first "project" is just going to be a simple audio splitter for an additional pair of speakers. I don't intend to use the two pairs of speakers at the same time, only one pair is going to be used at a time.

Here is my primitive schematic drawn by hand as it was quicker.

[image]

It will have four mono 6,3mm TS jacks. Two jacks will consist of the input (L & R), and two other pairs of will be the output.

Edit: Changed "TRS jacks" to "TS jacks" as pointed out by Kyle B

Will this will work, as I hope it will? Do I need to add additional components? I also might add an `ON-OFF-ON` toggle switch. In that case, how many pins will this switch need and how would I need to connect it?

Comment: Do the speakers have amplifiers, or are they passive speakers?

Comment: One is passive and the other is active. One of the outputs will of course go to the amplifier before to the speaker itself.

Comment: So the signal is not really a speaker signal, just line level audio signal? Just checking; you want to build it even if you can just buy these?

Comment: Just a comment from the peanut gallery....  If you have "four mono 6.3mm" jacks, they are not TRS.  TRS = TIP RING SLEEVE.   Mono jacks are just TIP SLEEVE  (TS).    https://www.sweetwater.com/sweetcare/articles/whats-the-difference-between-ts-and-trs-cables/

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit should work, with a *caveat* or two.

An output device has an output impedance. For example, a headphone output *might* be 8 ohms (Ω). If an 8 Ω headphone is connected, half the output voltage is dropped across each. That means the output to the amplified speaker would drop a bit (and tone might change, too) when the headphone is plugged in. For a headphone output jack, this would be a minor change.

Line outputs are often 600 Ω, and in that case, an 8 Ω headphone would be *very* low, and would also greatly drop volume for the amplified speaker.

Comment: Would the volume of the active speaker be affected even if the amp is turned off? Will a switch that alternates between either of the two speakers fix this issue?

Comment: Likely, the volume would only be affected by plugging/removing the passive speaker. It depends also on the source impedance: line or headphone output? Certainly, you could put in a DPDT switch, but it might or might not be needed.

Comment: I'd be surprised if a headphone output was 8 ohms. Why would you waste half the energy in the source, instead of making the output impedance as low as possible and getting almost all the energy into the load? We're not talking about high-frequency stuff where impedance matching really matters.